# Only get a maximum of 3 media gallery images getMediaGalleryImages in Magento

Tags: php, magento-1.7

We're currently loading a product's media gallery images on the Magento homepage using the following:-

```
<?php $_images = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId())->getMediaGalleryImages(); ?>    
<?php if($_images){?>            
    <?php $i=0; foreach($_images as $_image){ $i++; ?>
        <img class="gallery" src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize(255); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel());?>" title="<?php $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel());?>" />
    <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

This will currently get all of the product's media gallery images but we only wish to get a maximum of 3. Please could someone advise how the above can be rewrote to get only 3?

I'm unsure if  breaking the `foreach` loop is the best approach to this and as such I have played around with:-

```
<?php if (++$i == 3) break; ?>
```

But this doesn't seem to be consistent in only returning a maximum of 3.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get something to work by playing around with ideas:-

Changing:-

```
<?php $i=0; foreach($_images as $_image){ $i++; ?>
```

To...

```
<?php $i=0; foreach($_images as $_image) if ($i++ < 5) { $i++; ?>
```

This `if` statement in the `foreach` loop ensures that only a maximum of three are returned in the loop.

(I have no idea why because to me that looks like if value is greater than 5).

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP's native array_slice function before the loop.  The following will return a maximum of 3 and you won't waste time looping through unnecessary elements.

```
array_slice($_images, 0, 3)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php